# sequence flow from non-secure to secure

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, qualcomm, trustzone

I want to be sure if I understand the process describe non-secure high level os sending smc command.
According to Arm user manual and many blogs and articles, I think this is the following scenario:

1. EL0(non-secure) to EL1(non-secure) - svc
2. EL1(non-secure) to EL2(hypervisovr - non-secure) - smc/hvc
3. EL2(hypervisovr - non-secure) to EL3(monitor - non-secure) - smc
   note: here EL3(non-secure) change to EL3(secure)
4. EL3(monitor - secure) to EL1(secure) - ???
5. EL1(secure) to EL3(monitor - secure) - smc
   note: here EL3(secure) change to EL3(monitor - non-secure)
6. EL3(monitor - non-secure) to EL2(hypervisovr - non-secure) - eret
7. EL2(hypervisovr - non-secure) to EL1(non-secure) - eret
8. EL1(non-secure) to EL0(non-secure) - ret
   Can anyone fill in the blanks and correct me ?
   Thank,

Answer (score 0):

secure monitor uses `eret` to call into s-el1 from el3

read conduit section of `Arm Firmware Framework for Arm A-profile`